# Invalid syntax when using allowDiskUse:True through PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I got this problem when setting allowDiskUse to True, there are many similar questions about 'allowDiskUse' and none of them work in my case.
I use python 3.6.4 MongoDB 3.6.3 and pymongo 3.6.1

```
results = list(db.latest.aggregate([{"$match":{"markets":{"$eq":"play.google.com"}}},{"$group":{"_id":"$pkg_name","avg_vt_detection":{"$avg":"$vt_detection"}}}],allowDiskUse:True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allowDiskUse:True` is not valid Python syntax.

Perhaps you meant `allowDiskUse=True`?

Note the equals sign instead of a colon.

Comment: Thanks so much that works! all answer I have viewed was AllowDiskUse:True